# Duplicate column only with distinct values, others will become 0

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence

I would like to duplicate my ID column that has duplicate values, but in the new one that was generated only the values were unique, the others would be modified to 0

[image]

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: The maximum I got from logic was something like array reader in java with two pointers but I do not know if this type of logic works on power bi

Comment: What I understood was, you have multiple columns and want to maintain all the rows without removing duplicate valued rows. Please help me to clarify on following. If there are multiple duplicate values in a column, which data you want to retain as it is in the table (some conditional statement needed to make others as zero).

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove the duplicates, instead replace them for 0, the solution can be achieved through the Edit queries in PowerBI, by the filter remove duplicates as shown in the example below:

[image: Initial data with duplicates]

[image: Initial data without the duplicate values]

Tell me please if this solve your problem or need other solution!

Comment: I've tried using the Duplicates feature but it deletes rows that I still need, though, thank you very much for your response.